# Java EE Coding standards

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, coding-style

I have worked with servlets and JSPs for a while now, but I am looking to improve the way I write my J2EE code. I want to learn stuff like when to use properties file, how can I hide the database details from the user if I use JSP? Best way to create cookies? how to handle session management? etc etc., keen on know industry standard coding style. Can someone please share links for the tutorials? Thank you in advance.

Something like https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/Java+Coding+Guidelines would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest start learning to some framework. Its hard improve projects as set of un-organised jsp's.

My next step after first servlet was extremely light and simple to understand Maverick http://mav.sourceforge.net/

Very good way to feel request-based frameworks (like bigger Struts for example)

2. Read theoretical material about MVC pattern. This architecure patter HIDE unneded things from View (~== User)
3. JSP should be reduced only to View in MVC concept. Not every JSP programmer feel this problem. Thank You for plan to improve Your skils.

BTW: look at page in final form, in browser, there no database details here.

EDIT. Formally is ok using word (acronym) "JEE" to servlet & JSP projects, servlet belongs to this area, but this is only 1% of JEE complicity